# Codeigniter - FIles must be in the same folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I'm currently using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` to add text to an image. 
I have it working with all my files are in one folder, however I'm using CodeIgniter so my files are distributed throughout different folders.

What's the workaround to accomplish this?

I was thinking to put all my required files in my views, however that wasn't working.

**See error**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font

Filename: views/coupon.php

Line Number: 30

**See code**

```
<?php
//Report any errors
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Set the Content Type
      // header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

      // Create Image From Existing File
      $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost:8888/game/rcw/assets/couponWrite.jpg');


      // Allocate A Color For The Text
      $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 155, 155, 155);

      // Set Path to Font File
      $font_path = 'http://localhost:8888/game/rcw/application/views/Arial.ttf';

      // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
      $text = "IGL" . rand(55555,99999);

      // Print Text On Image
      imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

      // Send Image to Browser
      imagejpeg($jpg_image);

      // Clear Memory
      imagedestroy($jpg_image);


 ?>
```

Comment: What is the code you are using, what is the error you are running into? More information.

Comment: Sorry about that @Chilion,code and error have been added

Comment: Check your font path. Program is not able to find Arial.ttf in specified directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to access the image file using its path, either relative to the path of the PHP file that processes it, or better, its absolute path. For example, let's say your code is in a controller, in file `application/controllers/myImageProcessor.php` and you want to load a file stored in `application/input-files`, write something on it and store the modified version in `public/images`. You generate the paths of the files like this:

```
// input path is '../input-files/'
$inputPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/input-files/';            // this is an absolute path
$inputName = 'original.jpg';

// output path is '../../public/images/'
$outputPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/public/images/';
$outputName = 'modified.jpg';

// load image from file
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($inputPath.$inputName);

// ...
// write on $img here...
// ...

// save it to other file
imagejpeg($img, $outputPath.$outputName, 95);
```

It's not a good idea to store all the files in a single directory. Also, do not mix code with HTML/JS/CSS and never, ever, put in the same directory source files with generated files or files retrieved from external sources (uploaded by the users, for example).